# Getting dropdown menus to close when an item is selected

Tags: javascript, html, menu, dropdown, navbar

My webpage m1maths.com has a navbar with dropdown menus. I would like the menus to close when an item is selected, but they don't. A cut-down version of the navbar code is reproduced below. There is an html file with a bit of javascript which is meant to close the menus, followed by the css file.

I'm not good with javascript. The javascript in there is borrowed from the Internet. It is one of about 20 snippets from the Internet (including several from Stack Overflow) that I have tried without success. I have also tried writing my own and getting ChatGPT to write some. And I have asked three friends with some javascript knowledge to look at it. All without success. I am thinking that half a dozen lines of javascript should do the job if I can find the right code.

```js
// function to close all dropdown menus
function closeAllDropdowns() {
  const allDropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dd ul");
  allDropdowns.forEach(function(dropdown) {
    dropdown.classList.remove("show");
  });
}


// close all dropdown menus when document is clicked
document.documentElement.addEventListener("click", closeAllDropdowns);
```

```html
<table width="1000" border="0" align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>

        <div class="navbar">
          <ul class="dd">

            <li>
              <div class="dd__item"><a href="#Modules"> Modules &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </a></div>

              <ul class="dd ul">
                <li>
                  <div class="dd__item"> <a href="#A1">Algebra</a></div>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#A4">Level 4 (about Year 10)</a>
                      <li><a href="#A5">Level&nbsp5&nbsp(about&nbspYear&nbsp10)</a>
                        <li><a href="#A6">Level 6 (Years 11-12)</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  </li>

                  <li><a href="#SMA">Arithmetic</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why you have not used select input or bootstrap dropdown?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it with CSS and frameworks to be a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find updated code

```
// function to close all dropdown menus
function closeAllDropdowns() {    
    const allDropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dd ul");
    allDropdowns.forEach(function (dropdown) {
        // dropdown.classList.remove("show");
        dropdown.style.display = 'none';
    });
}

// function to open all dropdown menus
function openAllDropdowns() {    
    const allDropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dd ul");
    allDropdowns.forEach(function (dropdown) {        
        dropdown.style.display = '';
    });
}

// close/open all dropdown menus when document is clicked
document.documentElement.addEventListener("click", closeAllDropdowns);
document.documentElement.addEventListener("mouseover", openAllDropdowns);
```

Good Luck!!!

Comment: @user22373884 Did you try above updated JavaScript code ?

Comment: Hi @user:2176429 Jaydev Godvaishnav. Thank you so much for the updated code. I didn't get a chance to look at it until today. It works a dream on my laptop. However, it doesn't work so well on my phone. The menus won't drop down. I suspect this is because I can't mouseover on a phone, I have to tap the navbar. I've put the updated code into di.m1maths.com so you can see what happens on a phone. I tried to work out how to modify it, but I don't know enough.

Comment: Hi @user:2176429 Jaydev Godvaishnav. I've put a line at the start of the javascript: 'if (screen && screen.width > 719) {' . So now your code works on a desktop, but is ignored on a phone. So the problem is solved for desktop users a least. It would be great, though, to have something similar that works on a phone that I could put in another 'if' statement.